# RequireJS JQuery shim doesnt work with VS2013

Tags: javascript, requirejs, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get a requireJS shim for bootstrap going but im having a bit of trouble.

Whenever I run it in visual studio it breaks because of the new `__vwd/js/artery` javascript (which Visual Studio injects into the page) also references JQuery.

Is there a way to have my requireJS shim work in conjunction with artery?

below is some example html which will reproduce the issue (It works fine if you open it directly in a browser but breaks if you run it via Visual Studio (in my case I'm running it in an MVC app)

I can solve this by disabling artery but what im looking for is a way to leave it enabled and also be able to setup my shim.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        var require = {
            paths: {
                "jquery": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min",
                "bootstrap": "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min"
            },
            shim: {
                "bootstrap": ['jquery']
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        require(['bootstrap'], function () {
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="alert fade in" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `Browser link` is enabled by default in VS2013.

- If you are debuging your web application,You can uncheck “Enable Browser Link” and it will be turned off “ Browser Link” for all future requests made.
- You can also use the following appsettings in your web.config file.Set appSetting "vs:EnableBrowserLink" to "false". This will  disable Browser Link.

```xml
<appSettings>
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
<!--other settings -->
</appSettings>
```

Comment: @mat-mcloughlin it actually doesnt answer my question which is, how can I leave the browser link enabled and still use required jquery